# How can I customise the flexibleSpace property in SliverAppBar in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Instead of using FlexibleSpaceBar in the flexibleSpace property of SliverAppBar I want to use a custom widget tree, when expanded, but upon scrolling, I want to display a custom text, and not the widget tree.

I have created a custom widget tree which shall be assigned to the flexibleSpace property, but I don't know how to display custom text on scrolling, and hide the widget tree.

```
SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 180.0,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF9e0118),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          floating: true,
          pinned: true,
          flexibleSpace: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Some text',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontSize: 16.0),
                  )),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'some text',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                        fontSize: 16.0),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 15):

You may want to wrap your widget tree inside a `FlexibleSpaceBar` widget and add your widget tree as background. I hope I understood your question right. Check [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yesg4.jpg).

```
SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: 180.0,
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF9e0118),
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      floating: true,
      pinned: true,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
        centerTitle: true,
        background: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Some text',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                      fontSize: 16.0),
                )),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
                child: Text(
                  'some text',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                      fontSize: 16.0),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves a part of my problem which is that I can hide my custom widget tree on scrolling. The second part is that I also want to be able to display some text on the app bar while its pinned, and the user is scrolling, currently, its just blank with the red background.

Comment: Hey, I just saw your comment. Let me think and give you answer if it's not resolved yet.

Comment: Sure. Please do. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

To complete @westdabestdb answer, to make the title appear on scroll, it's really simple.

You just need to add the Animated Widget of you your choice and use the addListener from your scroll controller to switch a boolean. To find more Animated Widgets go to the official docs for Flutter Animated Widgets: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/animation

Here is an example with an AnimatedOpacity Widget and the Parallax collapse mode which in my opinion work pretty well together.

```
class YourPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const YourPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  ScrollController _scrollController;
  bool _isScrolled = false;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_listenToScrollChange);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 144.0,
              pinned: true,
              forceElevated: true,
              ////////////////////////////////////
              // HERE IS THE PART TO BE ADDED
              title: AnimatedOpacity(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                opacity: _isScrolled ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                curve: Curves.ease,
                child: Text("YOUR TITLE HERE"),
              ),
              ////////////////////////////////////
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                centerTitle: true,
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                background: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Some text',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              fontSize: 16.0),
                        )),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0, right: 32.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'some text',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'PlayfairDisplay',
                              fontSize: 16.0),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

// METHODS
  void _listenToScrollChange() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >= 48.0) {
      setState(() {
        _isScrolled = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isScrolled = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

You will just have to play around with the values of the if in the _listenToScrollChange 
 and the Duration of the animation to obtain the desired output.

Comment: I had a similar question, when I tried this answer I did get the desired output but the UI of the app became very laggy and slow. The response time decreased rapidly. Is there a workaround?

Comment: This method calls setState() on the entire widget tree too often which would surely make the UI laggy.

Comment: Yeah that's probably right, I didn't get to try it myself. To do a workaround, what you could do is to check if _isScrolled should be changed or not, resulting in less setStates. Just change the if to this => if(_scrollController.offset >= 48.0 && !_isScrolled) and else if(_isScrolled)